# Create countdown in rowview

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am a beginner in Appcelerator Titanium APP development. From the inspiration of this link I am trying to create a countdown timer to be work in TableRowView as each row have its own time set. And I customize this class to show Hours seconds like 5sec, 10 sec and so on.and when i click on first row countdown start and then click on second row , first row's countdown stop and again click first row ,the row countdown start from last stop

Comment: Provide more details with your question, also add what have you tried and see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for properly formatting your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
var timeInt = undefined;
function setTimer(obj){
if(timeInt != undefined){
    clearInterval(timeInt);
}
timeInt = setInterval(function(e){
    obj.text = (parseInt(obj.text) + 1);
},1000);
}
var arrRow= [];
$.winIndex.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height : 35
    });
    var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : "0",
        left : 10,
        right : 10,
        touchEnabled : false
    });
    row.lbl = lbl;
    row.add(lbl);
    arrRow.push(row);
}
$.tblView.data = arrRow;
});

$.tblView.addEventListener("click",function(e){
setTimer(e.source.lbl);
});
```

Thanks